# Where are the header files for the libiodbc included in Mac OS X 10.10?

Tags: macos, odbc

Mac OS X 10.10.5 has `/usr/lib/libiodbc.2.1.18.dylib` and `/usr/lib/libiodbcinst.2.1.18.dylib`, and the same two libraries are also found under the `MacOSX.10.10.sdk` (e.g. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/libiodbc.2.1.18.dylib`). Yet I cannot find the header files to go with it.

While I could grab some header files from the somewhere on the Internet, I'm concerned that whatever version I'd get might not match the version of the library that comes with Mac OS X. So which headers should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the headers aren't among system headers or in the 10.10 SDK. The last SDK version that appears to have them is 10.8 and the functions are tagged `DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_8_AND_LATER`; this macro is the main difference between 10.8 and earlier SDKs, 10.6 and 10.7 (the only other difference is the inclusion of `<objc/objc.h>` in iodbcunix.h). The dynamic library in all cases (10.6-8, 10.10) has the same version, so differences between the headers should be minor.

Your options would be to get the [iodbc headers](https://opensource.apple.com/source/iodbc/iodbc-42.5/iodbc/) from Apple's [open source](https://opensource.apple.com/) site (the versions in the 10.10 branches are identical to those in the 10.8 SDK) or copy them from the 10.7 or 10.8 SDK. From what I can find, the relevant files are:

- bin:

  - iodbc-config
- include:

  - iodbcext.h
  - iodbcinst.h
  - iodbcunix.h
  - isql.h
  - isqlext.h
  - isqltypes.h
  - odbcinst.h
  - sql.h
  - sqlext.h
  - sqltypes.h
  - sqlucode.h